# Middleware to parse body from string to float

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parsing, middleware

I'm in a nodejs app. I set in the index.js:

```js
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

I have two middleware:

**ParseFloatObj**: change the body from string to float, when possible.

**validationSchemaCalcolo**: is a schema of express-validation

My route is

```js
import {validationSchemaCalcolo} from '../middlewares/validation.js'
import ParseFloatObj from '../middlewares/ParseFloatObj.js' 
router.post(
  "/risultati",
  parseFloatObj,
  validationSchemaCalcolo,
  calcoloRisultati,
);
```

where calcoloRisultati is the controller.

ParseFloatObj:

```js
const parseFloatObj = (req, res, next) => {
  Object.keys(req.body).forEach(function (key, index) {
    let isNum = /^\d+.?\d*$/.test(req.body[key]);
    if (isNum == true) {
      req.body[key] = parseFloat(req.body[key]);
    }
  });
  next();
};

export default parseFloatObj;
```

validationSchemaObject:

```js
  export const validationSchemaCalcolo=checkSchema({ 
  '**':{
    trim:true,
    escape:true
  },
  percAutolisi: {
    custom:{
      options: async (value,{req})=> {
        const {autolisi,percAutolisi,percPrefermento1,percPrefermento2}=req.body
        if (autolisi=='SI' && (value<0 || value>80)) {throw new Error('inserire percentuale compresa tra 0 e 80')}
        if (percAutolisi+percPrefermento1+percPrefermento2>100) {throw new Error('la percentuale di autolisi + prefermento 1 + prefermento 2 è > 100%. Tale percentuale deve essere minore del 100%')}
        }
    }
  }
})
```

the problem is: when I get req.body in validationSchemaCalcolo, valdiating "percAutolisi" input, each value is still a string and not a float even if, at the end of parseFlaotObj all the body is float.

It looks like express.urlencoded always change data to string.

I want to find float numeber and not string in validationSchemaCalcolo.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you tried simply logging `req.body` in your `validationSchemaCalcolo` middleware? How are you verifying there's actually a problem?

Comment: FYI all values in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` are strings but your `parseFloatObj` looks like it should do what you want

Comment: I use VS Code's built-in debugger. The breackpoint at the end of ParseFloatObj shows req.body as float (e.g. pippo:30 pluto:40 paperino:3.56). It means the middleware works fine. The breackpoint in validationSchemaCalcolo shows pippo:'30' puto:'40' paperino:'3.56'. I've tried to change ParseFloatObj and add 1 to each value. In validationScehmaCalcolo I get the each value + 1... but they are always string. I can't understand.

Comment: It looks like the middleware are: urlencoded - parseFloatObj - urlencoded  - validationSchemaCalcolo - urlencoded -.....

Comment: No, that's not how it works

Comment: ok thanks Phil. what is the reason? can i try anything?

Answer (score -1):

I've found the problem, I think! In validationSchemaCalcolo I set:

```
 '**':{
    trim:true,
    escape:true
  },
```

... and so each float becomes a string.
thanks to the comments I've found the right direction where looking for the solution!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I added details. I hope the question is clearer, now. Thanks for your help and sorry if the question was unclear. Anyway the comments let me find the right direction to find the problem